# Sync of CSS Rainbow Animation

Tags: css, animation

I'm currently working on a YT Rainbow Theme. My problem is that I have more than one element with the rainbow animation and unfortunately there out of sync. For example, the YT Icon animation starts as soon as the site is loaded and the like / dislike button animation starts when on of the buttons gets clicked. 
My question is if there is a way to sync those two animations.

I thought that 'currentcolor' could be the solution to this problem, but I don't know where to place the animation that whenever I define a color with currentcolor the element gets the rainbow animation.

Srry for my bad English, I'm from Germany :)

This what my code looks like:

```
/*rainbow colors theme fill*/
@keyframes RainbowThemeF { 
    0% { fill: #ff0000 }
    5% { fill: #ff0074 }    
    10% { fill: #ff00b4 }
    15% { fill: #f000ff }
    20% { fill: #a300ff }
    25% { fill: #5600ff }
    30% { fill: #1500ff }
    35% { fill: #0051ff }
    40% { fill: #00abff }
    45% { fill: #00fff9 }
    50% { fill: #00ffb8 }
    55% { fill: #00ff78 }
    60% { fill: #00ff2b }
    65% { fill: #22ff00 }
    70% { fill: #6fff00 }
    75% { fill: #b0ff00 }
    80% { fill: #f0ff00 }
    85% { fill: #ffb400 }
    90% { fill: #ff7400 }
    95% { fill: #ff3300 }
    100% { fill: #ff0000 }
}
/*rainbow colors theme color*/
@keyframes RainbowThemeC { 
    0% { color: #ff0000 }
    5% { color: #ff0074 }    
    10% { color: #ff00b4 }
    15% { color: #f000ff }
    20% { color: #a300ff }
    25% { color: #5600ff }
    30% { color: #1500ff }
    35% { color: #0051ff }
    40% { color: #00abff }
    45% { color: #00fff9 }
    50% { color: #00ffb8 }
    55% { color: #00ff78 }
    60% { color: #00ff2b }
    65% { color: #22ff00 }
    70% { color: #6fff00 }
    75% { color: #b0ff00 }
    80% { color: #f0ff00 }
    85% { color: #ffb400 }
    90% { color: #ff7400 }
    95% { color: #ff3300 }
    100% { color: #ff0000 }
}
/*rainbow colors theme background color*/
@keyframes RainbowThemeBC { 
    0% { background-color: #ff0000 }
    5% { background-color: #ff0074 }    
    10% { background-color: #ff00b4 }
    15% { background-color: #f000ff }
    20% { background-color: #a300ff }
    25% { background-color: #5600ff }
    30% { background-color: #1500ff }
    35% { background-color: #0051ff }
    40% { background-color: #00abff }
    45% { background-color: #00fff9 }
    50% { background-color: #00ffb8 }
    55% { background-color: #00ff78 }
    60% { background-color: #00ff2b }
    65% { background-color: #22ff00 }
    70% { background-color: #6fff00 }
    75% { background-color: #b0ff00 }
    80% { background-color: #f0ff00 }
    85% { background-color: #ffb400 }
    90% { background-color: #ff7400 }
    95% { background-color: #ff3300 }
    100% { background-color: #ff0000 }
}
/*yt icon rainbow animation*/
#heart-button button yt-icon,
path[fill="#FF0000"] {
    animation: RainbowThemeF 35s linear infinite;
}
/*like bar rainbow animation*/
ytd-sentiment-bar-renderer[activated_] #like-bar.ytd-sentiment-bar-renderer {
    animation: RainbowThemeBC 35s linear infinite !important;
}
/*like / dislike button rainbow animation*/
ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-default-active[is-icon-button] {
    animation: RainbowThemeC 35s linear infinite !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scripting to apply the animation class to your elements that you wanted animated after the page has been loaded. Use something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //Code to apply classes to desired elements
});
```

Comment: I can only work with css since there is no support for javascript or html in stylish.

Comment: is there may be a way to restart all animation if a new one gets activated?

Comment: Try putting your keyframes code in a style tag at the bottom of your HTML

Comment: it is still out of sync :(